# php wordpress function, explanation on string in single quotes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Looking at the file in my editor it's a function and inside the function is a string in single quotes.

I have this wordpress function like so:

```
<div class="site-info">
                <?php do_action( 'focus_credits' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .site-info -->
```

When i inspect element in chrome it's like this:

```
<div class="site-info">
                Theme By yada yada yada and a link to their website here            </div>
```

My question is how is the literal string 'focus credits' returning the name of the theme and an href link to their website.

I've discovered the do_action function in the plugin.php

```
function do_action($tag, $arg = '') {
    global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $merged_filters, $wp_current_filter;

    if ( ! isset($wp_actions[$tag]) )
        $wp_actions[$tag] = 1;
    else
        ++$wp_actions[$tag];

    // Do 'all' actions first
    if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) ) {
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;
        $all_args = func_get_args();
        _wp_call_all_hook($all_args);
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter[$tag]) ) {
        if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )
            array_pop($wp_current_filter);
        return;
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter['all']) )
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;

    $args = array();
    if ( is_array($arg) && 1 == count($arg) && isset($arg[0]) && is_object($arg[0]) ) // array(&$this)
        $args[] =& $arg[0];
    else
        $args[] = $arg;
    for ( $a = 2; $a < func_num_args(); $a++ )
        $args[] = func_get_arg($a);

    // Sort
    if ( !isset( $merged_filters[ $tag ] ) ) {
        ksort($wp_filter[$tag]);
        $merged_filters[ $tag ] = true;
    }

    reset( $wp_filter[ $tag ] );

    do {
        foreach ( (array) current($wp_filter[$tag]) as $the_ )
            if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
                call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));

    } while ( next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );

    array_pop($wp_current_filter);
}
```

so his 'focus_credits' calling some text from the DB?

I looked through some of the tables but couldn't find anything relating..

Any help where to look would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do_action()` inserts an action hook in your template. If you dig through your theme's files, possibly `functions.php`, you should find a function that is hooked to this action hook:

```
add_action( 'focus_credits', 'focus_credits' );
function focus_credits(){
    echo 'Theme By yada yada yada and a link to their website here';    
}
```

More info on `do_action()`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action